# IIS/ASP file download different to original

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, download

Have the following code under IIS/ASP, with Chrome browser under Windows:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/exe";  //also tried application/octet-stream
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFile.exe");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/MyFile.exe"));
```

However when I complete the download, the file I downloaded is a different size to the original (the downloaded file is larger), and the digital sig is missing. How do I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/MyFile.exe"));
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", info.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFile.exe");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/MyFile.exe"));
```